# REGEX match (split ?) NAME , CITY and TIME (<= how to parse?)

Tags: php, regex, datetime, pcre

I am requesting following format from user

```
KEYWORD <name> , <city> , <24:00 hour time>
```

Point 5 is most important, I want to make sure I parse <24:00 hour time> in all possible ways that I can.
What I did/want
1. Split the input to get $info (= $input - $keyword) as follows:

```
$key = 'abc'; $msg = 'ABC blah, blah, blah';
$pat = "/^(?i)$key/";
$split = preg_split($pat, $msg);
$info = $split[1]; //$split[0] = ''; //empty string
```

2. My user is dumb. S/he will be "texting (SMS)" the input. So I want to split `$info` by char `,` (which hopefully will occur only twice) and store the three substrings into `$usName, $usCity, $usTime` respectively (prefix us = Un-Safe data, processed data goes into DB)
So I think I will do following

```
$split = preg_split('/,/', $info);
foeach($split as $block) {
    if(preg_match('/[12]?:\d{2}/', $block) {
        $usTime = $block;
    }
} //what do I do for $usName and $usCity
```

3. `$usName` goes directly into DB (don't worry I use prepared stmts)
4. `$usCity` needs to be mapped to a City in the DB table. I have indexed City_Variance and City_Key tables mapped to each other by City_Variance_City_Key table. So mistyped input can be mapped to proper indexed City name. For now assume that City_Variance has `/[:upper:]+/` so no multi word cities (i.e. NOT `Los Angeles`)
5. This is the most interesting part, the `$usTime`. The intended use of this field is to create an appointment in nearby future. Found [Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse). This is all PHP server side code, and I don't think I can use the power of a simple JavaScript library without simulating a browser
Does anyone know a library which can help me parse user input like [Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse)?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Could you simply remove the irrelevant parts instead of striking them out? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
KEYWORD <name> , <city> , <24:00 hour time>
```

and `"KEYWORD"` is `[:alpha:]+` and the other things cannot contain a comma, just use one regex with sub-groups instead of `split()`.

```php
$re = "/
^
[A-Z]+\s*
([^,]+)\s*,\s*
([^,]+)\s*,\s*
((?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])
$
/x";

$msg = 'ABC blah, blah, 12:45';

$result=null;

preg_match($re, $msg, $result);

print_r($result);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC blah, blah, 12:45
    [1] => blah
    [2] => blah
    [3] => 12:45
)
```

Comment: cleaned up stuff, would you like to comment on parsing TIME part ?

Comment: how do I include `HH:MM` (or) `HH.MM` . Does this look correct to you : `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[:.][0-5][0-9])` ?

Comment: @Sudhi Yes, that's correct. You can use `\d?\d[.:]\d\d` if you do not care for *validating* the numeric ranges. My variant accepts valid times from `00:00` through `23:59` only. There is a plethora of [date and time functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php), you will find one that does validation etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, people over PHP chat room suggested strtotime, so I think I will skip the last bit of your regex and instead validate/create DateTime using strtotime

Comment: update on last comment, seems like date_create() is much more useful than strtotime , thanks again for your regex

Comment: @Sudhi Seems a good approach to me. If you already must do post-processing and validation, there is no need to do things in a regex that can be done more easily (and more readably) with the appropriate function.